# Vectorization of multifold summation to speedup

Tags: performance-tuning, summation, numerical-value

I searched this website but didn't find any suitable answer describing how one can speed up summation in Mathematica using vectorization techniques and other techniques.

I often have to numerically sum over a multi-fold series of the hypergeometric type in my research work. One toy example is

```
lim = 150;
Sum[
  Gamma[1 + n1 + n2 + n3]/(n1! n2! n3!) (0.1)^n1 (0.1)^n2 (0.1)^
   n3, {n1, 0, lim}, {n2, 0, lim}, {n3, 0, lim}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

which takes about 42 sec on my laptop.
The only way I know to speed-up is by using `ParallelSum` instead of `Sum`, which takes 9 sec, thanks to my 8 core processor.
I want to know if there are any tricks or techniques to speed-up?

Comment: The best way is probably to exploit the fact that the summands decay quite rapidly. If I set `lim = 20` the summation is 100 times as fast and has still a precision of 15 digits...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be useful as an idea, but @Henrik's observation suggests a superior approach on the case at hand. The following takes a single-core run of the OP's code from around 40s down to a little over 1s on 4 cores.  Using `Map` instead of `ParallelMap` takes about three times as long.  The code uses the highly efficient `Outer[List,...]` to construct the array of inputs and `LogGamma` instead of `Gamma` to keep the numerics in the machine-number realm.

```
lim = 150;
log10 = Log[0.1];
ParallelMap[
   Apply@Function[{n1, n2, n3}, 
     Total[
       LogGamma[1 + n1 + n2 + n3] - LogGamma[1 + n1] - 
         LogGamma[1 + n2] - LogGamma[1 + n3] + (n1 + n2 + n3) log10 //
         Exp, 2]],
   Transpose[
    Outer[List, Range[0., lim], Range[0., lim], Range[0., lim]],
    {1, 3, 4, 2}]
   ] // Total // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*  {1.14043, 1.42857}  *)
> ```

Demonstration of Henrik's comment:

```
lim = 20;
log10 = Log[0.1];
res2 = ParallelMap[
    Apply@
     Function[{n1, n2, n3}, 
      Total[
        LogGamma[1 + n1 + n2 + n3] - LogGamma[1 + n1] - 
          LogGamma[1 + n2] - LogGamma[1 + n3] + (n1 + n2 + n3) log10 //
          Exp, 2]],
    Transpose[
     Outer[List, Range[0., lim], Range[0., lim], Range[0., lim]],
     {1, 3, 4, 2}]
    ] // Total // AbsoluteTiming
res - res2 // Last
```

> ```
> (*
>   {0.01348, 1.42857}
>   -6.66134*10^-16
> *)
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Indeed, Henrik's comment is useful for this toy sum, but Michael's method is useful for a general hypergeometric series.

Answer (score 2):

Your toy example admits another approach that may be helpful. First, note that:

$$\Gamma (n+1)=\int_0^{\infty } t^n e^{-t} \, dt$$

So, your original expression can be rewritten as (assuming the order of integration and summation can be interchanged):

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} \left(\sum _{n=0}^L \frac{a^n t^n}{n!}\right){}^3 \, \
dt$$

The sum can be computed:

```
Sum[(a^n t^n)/n!, {n, 0, L}]
```

> (E^(a t) Gamma[1 + L, a t])/Gamma[1 + L]

So, your original expression is equivalent to the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-t} \left(\frac{e^{a t} \Gamma (L+1,a t)}{\Gamma (L+1)}\right)^3 \, dt$$

A function that does this computation:

```
s[a_, L_, opts:OptionsPattern[NIntegrate]] := NIntegrate[
    Exp[-t] (Exp[a t] Gamma[L+1, a t]/Gamma[L+1])^3,
    {t, 0, Infinity},
    opts
]
```

Your example:

```
s[1/10, 150, WorkingPrecision -> 50] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.144731, 1.4285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714}

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very nice approach.

Comment: But for the more general case where we have at least 4-5 Euler gamma functions in the numerator, this approach might not be so efficient as we will have to perform a multi-fold integration.